# accidentally mv’ed all contents of / to a different directory

Tags: 18.04

So I was playing around with my file system, and I have a directory with a space at the end of its name so I did mv /name /* /destination but I didn’t realize that it would move everything in my file system to /destination, and now nothing works. Can I fix this? I tried moving everything back, but I don’t have adequate permissions and no commands work because /bin is now /destination/bin.

Comment: Reinstall the system. This is the fastest and easiest way with your skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Boot from a live-USB.
- Open a terminal as root (with `sudo -s`).
- Find the storage device affected, on which you were working, with `fdisk -l`. I'll call it `/dev/sdx1`, but of course you should substitute the final part (sdx1) with the correct device partition.
- Mount it with `mount /dev/sdx1 /mnt`.
- Issue `mv /mnt/destination/* /mnt`.
- Dismount it with `umount /dev/sdx1`.
- Shutdown, remove USB, boot normally.

  You should have it all fixed.